# How to develop sbt plugin in multi-project build with projects that use it?

Tags: sbt

Is it possible to build an sbt plugin in a multi-project setup and use that plugin in some other sub-project of the same multi-project?

For example:

```
root/
+  mySbtPlugin/
+  myProject/
   +  project/
      +  plugins.sbt    // Uses `mySbtPlugin`
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is **not** possible since the only way to define plugins for a single or multi-module project is via `project` (meta)build. I was tricked again to have a solution for you when I set up the sandbox environment with the layout you described.

sbt allows `project` (meta)project to be in the root directory only. No other `project` directories are processed and become part of the build definition.

That's why your best (and only) bet is to have the multi-module build for `myProject` and `mySbtPlugin` to ease your development, and enable the plugin only for these project(s) you really want to (be careful with [auto-plugins](http://typesafe.com/blog/preview-of-upcoming-sbt-10-features-read-about-the-new-plugins), though).

**project/plugins.sbt**

```
lazy val root = (project in file(".")) dependsOn sbtNonamePlugin

lazy val sbtNonamePlugin = ProjectRef(file("../sbt-noname"), "sbt-noname")

addSbtPlugin("pl.japila" % "sbt-noname" % "1.0")
```

**build.sbt**

```
lazy val `my-project`, `sbt-noname` = project
```

**sbt-noname/build.sbt**

```
sbtPlugin := true

name := "sbt-noname"

organization := "pl.japila"

version := "1.0"
```

**sbt-noname/src/main/scala/sbtnoname/Plugin.scala**

```
package sbtnoname

import sbt._
import plugins._

object Plugin extends AutoPlugin {

  override def trigger = allRequirements

  override val projectSettings: Seq[Setting[_]] = inConfig(Test)(baseNonameSettings)

  lazy val sayHello = taskKey[Unit]("Say hello")

  lazy val baseNonameSettings: Seq[sbt.Def.Setting[_]] = Seq(
    sayHello := {
      println("I'm the plugin to say hello")
    }
  )
}
```

With the files above, run `sbt`.

```
> about
[info] This is sbt 0.13.6-SNAPSHOT
[info] The current project is {file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/multi-plugin/}my-project 0.1-SNAPSHOT
[info] The current project is built against Scala 2.10.4
[info] Available Plugins: sbt.plugins.IvyPlugin, sbt.plugins.JvmPlugin, sbt.plugins.CorePlugin, sbt.plugins.JUnitXmlReportPlugin, sbtnoname.Plugin, com.timushev.sbt.updates.UpdatesPlugin
[info] sbt, sbt plugins, and build definitions are using Scala 2.10.4
> projects
[info] In file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/multi-plugin/
[info]   * multi-plugin
[info]     my-project
[info]     sbt-noname
> plugins
In file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/multi-plugin/
    sbt.plugins.IvyPlugin: enabled in multi-plugin, sbt-noname, my-project
    sbt.plugins.JvmPlugin: enabled in multi-plugin, sbt-noname, my-project
    sbt.plugins.CorePlugin: enabled in multi-plugin, sbt-noname, my-project
    sbt.plugins.JUnitXmlReportPlugin: enabled in multi-plugin, sbt-noname, my-project
    sbtnoname.Plugin: enabled in multi-plugin, sbt-noname, my-project
> my-project/test:sayHello
I'm the plugin to say hello
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed Jun 15, 2014 3:49:50 PM
```