# Intertwined dependencies between sbt plugin and projects within multi-project build that uses the plugin itself

Tags: scala, plugins, sbt

I'm developing a library that includes an sbt plugin. Naturally, I'm using sbt to build this (multi-project) library. My (simplified) project looks as follows:

```
myProject/                        # Top level of library
  -> models                       # One project in the multi-project sbt build.
      -> src/main/scala/...       # Defines common models for both sbt-plugin and framework
  -> sbt-plugin                   # The sbt plugin build
      -> src/main/scala/...
  -> framework                    # The framework. Ideally, the sbt plugin is run as part of 
      -> src/main/scala/...       # compiling this directory.
  -> project/                     # Multi-project build configuration
```

Is there a way to have the sbt-plugin defined in myProject/sbt-plugin be hooked into the build for myProject/framework all in a unified build?

Note: similar (but simpler) question: [How to develop sbt plugin in multi-project build with projects that use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24228553)

Answer (score 7):

> Is there a way to have the sbt-plugin defined in myProject/sbt-plugin be hooked into the build for myProject/framework all in a unified build?

I have a working example on Github [eed3si9n/plugin-bootstrap](https://github.com/eed3si9n/plugin-bootstrap). It's not super pretty, but it kind of works. We can take advantage of the fact that [sbt is recursive](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Organizing-Build.html#sbt+is+recursive).

> The `project` directory is *another build inside your build*, which knows how to build your build. To distinguish the builds, we sometimes use the term **proper build** to refer to your build, and **meta-build** to refer to the build in `project`. The projects inside the metabuild can do anything any other project can do. *Your build definition is an sbt project.*

By extension, we can think of the sbt plugins to be library- or inter-project dependencies to the root project of your metabuild.

### meta build definition (`project/plugins.sbt`)

In this example, think of the metabuild as a parallel universe or shadow world that has parallel multi-build structure as the proper build (`root`, `model`, `sbt-plugin`).

To reuse the source code from `model` and `sbt-plugin` subprojects in the proper build, we can re-create the multi-project build in the metabuild. This way we don't need to get into the circular dependency.

```
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-doge" % "0.1.5")

lazy val metaroot = (project in file(".")).
  dependsOn(metaSbtSomething)

lazy val metaModel = (project in file("model")).
  settings(
    sbtPlugin := true,
    scalaVersion := "2.10.6",
    unmanagedSourceDirectories in Compile :=
      mirrorScalaSource((baseDirectory in ThisBuild).value.getParentFile / "model")
  )

lazy val metaSbtSomething = (project in file("sbt-plugin")).
  dependsOn(metaModel).
  settings(
    sbtPlugin := true,
    scalaVersion := "2.10.6",
    unmanagedSourceDirectories in Compile :=
      mirrorScalaSource((baseDirectory in ThisBuild).value.getParentFile / "sbt-plugin")
  )

def mirrorScalaSource(baseDirectory: File): Seq[File] = {
  val scalaSourceDir = baseDirectory / "src" / "main" / "scala"
  if (scalaSourceDir.exists) scalaSourceDir :: Nil
  else sys.error(s"Missing source directory: $scalaSourceDir")
}
```

When sbt loads up, it will build `metaModel` and `metaSbtSomething` first, and use `metaSbtSomething` as a plugin to your proper build.

If you have any other plugins you need you can just add it to `project/plugins.sbt` normally as I've added `sbt-doge`.

### proper build (build.sbt)

The proper build looks like a normal multi-project build.
As you can see `framework` subproject uses `SomethingPlugin`. Important thing is that they share the source code, but the `target` directory is completely separated, so there are no interference once the proper build is loaded, and you are changing code around.

```
import Dependencies._

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).
  aggregate(model, framework, sbtSomething).
  settings(inThisBuild(List(
      scalaVersion := scala210,
      organization := "com.example"
    )),
    name := "Something Root"
  )

// Defines common models for both sbt-plugin and framework
lazy val model = (project in file("model")).
  settings(
    name := "Something Model",
    crossScalaVersions := Seq(scala211, scala210)
  )

// The framework. Ideally, the sbt plugin is run as part of building this.
lazy val framework = (project in file("framework")).
  enablePlugins(SomethingPlugin).
  dependsOn(model).
  settings(
    name := "Something Framework",
    crossScalaVersions := Seq(scala211, scala210),
    // using sbt-something
    somethingX := "a"
  )

lazy val sbtSomething = (project in file("sbt-plugin")).
  dependsOn(model).
  settings(
    sbtPlugin := true,
    name := "sbt-something",
    crossScalaVersions := Seq(scala210)
  )
```

### demo

In the `SomethingPlugin` example, I'm defining `something` task that uses `foo.Model.x`.

```
package foo

import sbt._

object SomethingPlugin extends AutoPlugin {
  def requries = sbt.plugins.JvmPlugin
  object autoImport {
    lazy val something = taskKey[Unit]("")
    lazy val somethingX = settingKey[String]("")
  }
  import autoImport._
  override def projectSettings = Seq(
    something := { println(s"something! ${Model.x}") }
  )
}
```

Here's how we can invoke `something` task from the build:

```
Something Root> framework/something
something! 1
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed May 29, 2016 3:01:07 PM
```

`1` comes from `foo.Model.x`, so this demonstrates that we are using the sbt-something plugin in `framework` subproject, and that the plugin is using `metaModel`.